# ROC of $\mathcal{Z}$-Transform and zeros

Tags: z-transform, poles-zeros

**Theorem:** Let $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nz^n$$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$.
If $f(z_0)$ exists for some $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ then it converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|\lt|z_0|$.
**Proof:** It follows from the hypothesis that $\exists M\ge0 : |a_nz_0^n|\le M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We have $|a_nz^n|=|a_nz_0^n||\frac{z}{z_0}|^n\le M|\frac{z}{z_0}|^n$. By the comparison theorem and the behavior of geometric series, we conclude that $f(z)$ converges for $|z|<|z_0|$.

So if we choose $z_0$ such that $f(z_0) = 0$, then $f(z)$ converges for $|z|\lt|z_0|$(Because $f(z_0) = 0$ means that $f(z_0)$ exists). In other words, ROC of $\mathcal{Z}$-Transform depends on the location of poles as well as zeros of $f(z)$ but according to the literature, ROC depends only on the location of poles. So what's my mistake here? Does the location of zeros affect the ROC?

Comment: Why do you think you get to choose $z_0$?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: I think the OP means to say that $z_0$ simply is a zero of $X(z)$, so $X(z_0)=0$ is satisfied, and, hence - at least according to the OP - $X(z)$ should converge for any $z$ satisfying $|z|<|z_0|$ (because it apparently converges for $z=z_0$).

Comment: I'm confused. As far as I understand poles and zeros are defined for systems but the Z-transform is applied to signals.  What's the pole of a signal ?

Comment: @Hilmar: $x[n]$ is just a sequence; its interpretation is irrelevant here, isn't it? We usually compute Z-transforms of signals *and* of impulse responses, so both interpretations are fine I guess.

Comment: @MattL. I don't understand that argument.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac I edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: I'm not sure I understand it, but that's my interpretation of the question. I think the OP's argument goes as follows: if $X(z)$ converges for some $z_0$ then it must converge for all $z$ satisfying $|z|<|z_0|$. If $z_0$ is a zero of $X(z)$ then $X(z_0)=0$ holds, and, consequently, $X(z)$ converges for $z_0$, hence it converges for all $z$ satisfying $|z|<|z_0|$.

Comment: @MattL. Yes, exactly.

Comment: @S.H.W. I'm not sure what you're trying to argue. Your argument is circular. Assume it converges, then it converges.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac I'm asking this question: How the location of zeros affect the ROC given the mentioned theorem? We always consider just the location of poles. Is that sufficient? Because it seems to me the mentioned theorem put some restrictions on the ROC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because $f(z)$ converges for $|z|\le|z_0|$ for your choice of $\{ z_0 : f(z_0) = 0\}$ doesn't imply that $f(z)$ can't converge for $|z| \gt |z_0|$ also... up until the pole of next greatest magnitude.

Comment: Thanks. So this theorem doesn't restrict ROC in any way? I mean it seems to me that this theorem shows ROC and location of zeros are related and should be considered.

Comment: @S.H.W Right: it tells you part of where the ROC is, it just doesn't tell you everything about where the ROC is.